C# FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync never finishes
I have an EXE built with C# in .NET 4.8, and I need to
"Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1"
to keep sending push notifications to Android devices.
The old setup used no SDK and simply posts to the FCM API with a key in a header.
For the new setup, I have added the FirebaseAdmin SDK and have imported Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
The problem is, that when SendAsync is called (see below), it never finishes. Message is not sent.
Any suggestions?
Below is the code.
    public async Task<string> SendMessage()
    {
        string bericht = "test HTTP v1 GJS";
        string firebaseToken = "a-valid-token";  // real code has a real value

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging" };
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "my-service-account-json-download.json");
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path).CreateScoped(scopes),
        });

        var message = new Message
        {
            Token = firebaseToken,
            Notification = new Notification
            {
                Title = bericht,
            }
        };
    
        // the following line never finishes!
        string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
    
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        return response;
    }


Update: the code did work. The problem was in the handling of Task<string>. In SendMessage, I now simply use
return FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

And I call SendMessage with
string line = await mfb.SendMessage();

Thanks for your interest and support.

I'm using the assembly Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1 to send messages:
var credentialJson = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"myFirebaseFileFromAdminSDK.json"); //get my credentials file

You'll need a bearer token from Google:
var bearer = "";
var scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirebaseCloudMessagingUrl"];
using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    bearer = await GoogleCredential
        .FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped(scope)
        .UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
}

Create a message object to pass in:
Message msg = new Message
{
    data = new Data(),
};

Add your device's firebase token when you registered your device in firebase console:
msg.token = "my-firebase-token";

Add some message content (you can create a notification object as well)
msg.data.title = "your ticket status";
msg.data.body = "64bit-image";

Add a message root object:
var msgRoot = new Root
{
    message = msg,
    validate_only = false
};

Then send her away...
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirebaseCloudMessagingSendUrl"];

var msgResult = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, msgRoot, headers =>
{
    headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer);
});

var content = await msgResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (msgResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return Ok();
}
else
{
    return NotFound();
}

